# I have created an API. Using ajax, I want to output the weather. I'm specifically looking for the description and the temperature

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, dom

I was able to innerHTMl and output the temperature. I have a hard time accessing description of weather object. Also, how would I display the two values of temp and description at the same time?

I have created the API here https://mm214.com/jsondemo.php

```html
<span id="temp"></span>
<span id="weather"></span>
<script>
const getJSON = function(url, callback) {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('get', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onload = function() {
      let status = xhr.status;
      if (status == 200) {
        callback(null, xhr.response);
      } else {
        callback(status);
      }
    };
    xhr.send();
};

getJSON('https://mm214.com/jsondemo.php', function(err, data) {
  if (err != null) {
    alert('Something went wrong: ' + err);
  } else {
    document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = data.main.temp
    // document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = data.main.pressure;
    //lert('Your Json result is:  ' + data.result);
  }
});

</script>
```

Comment: Your code works fine - I've made it a code snippet - when you run it, it works

Comment: sorry, just re-read the question ... use `data.weather[0].description`

Comment: Do you want to print temp and description? Try this
var tempJson = data.main.temp;
var tempJson1 = data.weather[0].description;
document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = tempJson + " " + tempJson1;

Answer (score 1):

I give an sample code for your reference:

```js
let data = {
  "coord": {
    "lon": -0.13,
    "lat": 51.51
  },
  "weather": [{
    "id": 300,
    "main": "Drizzle",
    "description": "light intensity drizzle",
    "icon": "09d"
  }],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 280.32,
    "pressure": 1012,
    "humidity": 81,
    "temp_min": 279.15,
    "temp_max": 281.15
  },
  "visibility": 10000,
  "wind": {
    "speed": 4.1,
    "deg": 80
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 90
  },
  "dt": 1485789600,
  "sys": {
    "type": 1,
    "id": 5091,
    "message": 0.0103,
    "country": "GB",
    "sunrise": 1485762037,
    "sunset": 1485794875
  },
  "id": 2643743,
  "name": "London",
  "cod": 200
};


document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = data.main.temp;
document.getElementById("weather").innerHTML = data.weather[0].description;
```

```html
<span id="temp"></span>
<span id="weather"></span>
```

Comment: Ahhh, thank you so much. What is the explanation for [0]? I'm somewhat familiar accessing with it, but what is the logic in this scenario?

Comment: It is because the `data.weather` is an array. So, if you need to access the first element of the array, you have to use [0] syntax. Because the javascript array is zero-indexed, the first element of an array is at index 0, the second is at index 1, and so on — and the last element is at the value of the array's length property minus 1.